# Convergence of Series over Multi-integers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given a dimension $n\in\mathbb{N}$, is there an easy way to say why the following sum over the multi-integers should converge?  (By $\|k\|$ I mean the Euclidian distance on $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

$$\underset{k\in\mathbb{Z}^n\setminus\{0\}}{\sum}\|k\|e^{-\|k\|}.$$

In one dimension, the ratio test gives the conclusion.  My assumption is that we can say there are $C$ elements of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ that have the same distance where $C$ is some constant depending on the dimension, and then we essentially have maybe $C$ copies of the series $\sum ne^{-n}$.

Comment: how about counting the approximate number of integer points in a N-sphere and working from there

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to get involved with the particulars of the formula. A general fact is:

> If $f(x)=O(x^{-p})$ as $ x\to +\infty$, where $p>n $, then $\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z^n} f(\|k\|) $ converges absolutely.

We can replace $f$ with $|f|$, thus reducing the $f$ being nonnegative. For each $j\in\mathbb N$ there are $O(2^{jn})$ lattice elements with $2^{j}\le |k|<2^{j+1} $, and they contribute $O(2^{-jp})$ each ($O$ symbols uniform in $j$). So, the contribution of the $j$th  dyadic spherical shell is $O(2^{(n-p)j})$. This gives a convergent geometric series.

The fact that $e^{-x} = O(x^{-p})$ for every $p$ is standard.